How to access Label given out by function using lambda
I started coding 2 weeks ago so i am a beginner and probably there is an easy solution for my problem but i can't solve it. Currently I am trying to build Tic Tac Toe in Python with tkinter. Now to check if someone has won I need to be able to access the text in the labels which appear when one button is clicked.
My code:
import tkinter as tk
count = 2


def spielfeld_generieren():
    Startknopf.destroy()

    ueberschrift = tk.Label(Display, text="X Beginnt!", font=("Arial", 10))
    ueberschrift.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)

    first = tk.Button(Display, height=10, width=20, command=lambda: nutzereingabe(first, 1, 0))
    first.grid(row=1, column=0, )

    second = tk.Button(Display, height=10, width=20, command=lambda: nutzereingabe(second, 1, 1))
    second.grid(row=1, column=1)

    third = tk.Button(Display, height=10, width=20, command=lambda: nutzereingabe(third, 1, 2))
    third.grid(row=1, column=2)

    fourth = tk.Button(Display, height=10, width=20, command=lambda: nutzereingabe(fourth, 2, 0))
    fourth.grid(row=2, column=0)

    fifth = tk.Button(Display, height=10, width=20, command=lambda: nutzereingabe(fifth, 2, 1))
    fifth.grid(row=2, column=1)

    six = tk.Button(Display, height=10, width=20, command=lambda: nutzereingabe(six, 2, 2))
    six.grid(row=2, column=2)

    seven = tk.Button(Display, height=10, width=20, command=lambda: nutzereingabe(seven, 3, 0))
    seven.grid(row=3, column=0)

    eight = tk.Button(Display, height=10, width=20, command=lambda: nutzereingabe(eight, 3, 1))
    eight.grid(row=3, column=1)

    nine = tk.Button(Display, height=10, width=20, command=lambda: nutzereingabe(nine, 3, 2))
    nine.grid(row=3, column=2)


def nutzereingabe(position, a, b):
    position.destroy()
    global count
    if count % 2 == 0:
        ausgabe = "X"
        color = "red"
    else:
        ausgabe = "O"
        color = "black"
    name = tk.Label(Display, text=ausgabe, fg=color, font=("Arial", 100), height=1, width=2)
    name.grid(row=a, column=b)
    count += 1


Display = tk.Tk()
Display.title("Tic Tac Toe")

Startknopf = tk.Button(Display, text="Start the game", command=spielfeld_generieren)
Startknopf.pack()


Display.mainloop()


Originally I thought the Labels will have the name of the variable Parameter "position" (Like "first", "second", "third" ...). But that's not the case because then i get the error that this name is not defined. I also tried renaming the Labels but for that i also need their name.


I need to be able to access the text in the labels which appear when
one button is clicked.

The problem can be fixed.

Move Display = tk.Tk() to top before spielfeld_generieren()
function'
Move ueberschrift widget outside of function.
Add ueberschrift.configure inside spielfeld_generieren()function.
Add both ueberschrift.configure(text="O turn!") and
ueberschrift.configure(fg='black') inside nutzereingabe function.
Add both ueberschrift.configure(text="X turn!") and
ueberschrift.configure(fg='red') inside nutzereingabe function.
Change pack() to Startknopf.grid()

Snippet re-modified:
import tkinter as tk
count = 2

Display = tk.Tk()

def spielfeld_generieren():
    Startknopf.destroy()
    ueberschrift.configure(text="X Beginnt!")

    first = tk.Button(Display, height=10, width=20, command=lambda: nutzereingabe(first, 1, 0))
    first.grid(row=1, column=0, )

    second = tk.Button(Display, height=10, width=20, command=lambda: nutzereingabe(second, 1, 1))
    second.grid(row=1, column=1)

    third = tk.Button(Display, height=10, width=20, command=lambda: nutzereingabe(third, 1, 2))
    third.grid(row=1, column=2)

    fourth = tk.Button(Display, height=10, width=20, command=lambda: nutzereingabe(fourth, 2, 0))
    fourth.grid(row=2, column=0)

    fifth = tk.Button(Display, height=10, width=20, command=lambda: nutzereingabe(fifth, 2, 1))
    fifth.grid(row=2, column=1)

    six = tk.Button(Display, height=10, width=20, command=lambda: nutzereingabe(six, 2, 2))
    six.grid(row=2, column=2)

    seven = tk.Button(Display, height=10, width=20, command=lambda: nutzereingabe(seven, 3, 0))
    seven.grid(row=3, column=0)

    eight = tk.Button(Display, height=10, width=20, command=lambda: nutzereingabe(eight, 3, 1))
    eight.grid(row=3, column=1)

    nine = tk.Button(Display, height=10, width=20, command=lambda: nutzereingabe(nine, 3, 2))
    nine.grid(row=3, column=2)


def nutzereingabe(position, a, b):
    position.destroy()
    global count
    if count % 2 == 0:
        ausgabe = "X"
        color = "red"
        ueberschrift.configure(text="O turn!")
        ueberschrift.configure(fg='black')
    else:
        ausgabe = "O"
        color = "black"
        ueberschrift.configure(text="X Turn")
        ueberschrift.configure(fg='red')
    name = tk.Label(Display, text=ausgabe, fg=color, font=("Arial", 100), height=1, width=2)
    name.grid(row=a, column=b)
    count += 1

ueberschrift = tk.Label(Display, font=("Arial", 10))
ueberschrift.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)

 
Display.title("Tic Tac Toe")

Startknopf = tk.Button(Display, text="Start the game", command=spielfeld_generieren)
Startknopf.grid()


Display.mainloop()

Edit:
Btw, we will not emphasize the winning score.
You will have to emphasize to write a function.
Screenshot:


Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem.

You actually don't need to access the text of the labels. You already check player turns in nutzereingabe. Just use another argument in your lambda function. I have created an example, where I put this positional argument into seperate lists for X or O. Each time a button is clicked, it checks if one of the win conditions is met in the list. I also added a restart button and disabled all buttons once someone wins. I shared a lot of variables accross functions with global. This should actually be avoided as much as possible, but for learning it is okay to do.
import tkinter as tk


def spielfeld_generieren():
    global buttons
    global X, O, count
    global ueberschrift

    count = 2
    X = []
    O = []

    Startknopf.destroy()
    try:
        ueberschrift.destroy()
    except:
        pass
    ueberschrift = tk.Label(Display, text="X Beginnt!", font=("Arial", 10))
    ueberschrift.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)

    first = tk.Button(Display, height=10, width=20, command=lambda: nutzereingabe(first, 1, 0, 1))
    first.grid(row=1, column=0)

    second = tk.Button(Display, height=10, width=20, command=lambda: nutzereingabe(second, 1, 1, 2))
    second.grid(row=1, column=1)

    third = tk.Button(Display, height=10, width=20, command=lambda: nutzereingabe(third, 1, 2, 3))
    third.grid(row=1, column=2)

    fourth = tk.Button(Display, height=10, width=20, command=lambda: nutzereingabe(fourth, 2, 0, 4))
    fourth.grid(row=2, column=0)

    fifth = tk.Button(Display, height=10, width=20, command=lambda: nutzereingabe(fifth, 2, 1, 5))
    fifth.grid(row=2, column=1)

    six = tk.Button(Display, height=10, width=20, command=lambda: nutzereingabe(six, 2, 2, 6))
    six.grid(row=2, column=2)

    seven = tk.Button(Display, height=10, width=20, command=lambda: nutzereingabe(seven, 3, 0, 7))
    seven.grid(row=3, column=0)

    eight = tk.Button(Display, height=10, width=20, command=lambda: nutzereingabe(eight, 3, 1, 8))
    eight.grid(row=3, column=1)

    nine = tk.Button(Display, height=10, width=20, command=lambda: nutzereingabe(nine, 3, 2, 9))
    nine.grid(row=3, column=2)

    buttons = [first, second, third, fourth, fifth, six, seven, eight, nine]


def nutzereingabe(pressed_button, a, b, pos):
    global count
    global X
    global O
    global ueberschrift

    pressed_button.destroy()

    if count % 2 == 0:
        ausgabe = "X"
        color = "red"
        X.append(pos)
    else:
        ausgabe = "O"
        color = "black"
        O.append(pos)

    name = tk.Label(Display, text=ausgabe, fg=color, font=("Arial", 100), height=1, width=2)
    name.grid(row=a, column=b)

    # win conditions
    conditions = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9], [1, 5, 9], [3, 5, 7]]

    for c in conditions:
        if set(c).issubset(X):
            ueberschrift = tk.Label(Display, text="X hat gewonnen!", font=("Arial", 10, "bold"))
            ueberschrift.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)
            deactivate_button()
            Startknopf = tk.Button(Display, text="Restart the game", command=spielfeld_generieren)
            Startknopf.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=3)

        elif set(c).issubset(O):
            ueberschrift = tk.Label(Display, text="O hat gewonnen!", font=("Arial", 10, "bold"))
            ueberschrift.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)
            deactivate_button()
            Startknopf = tk.Button(Display, text="Restart the game", command=spielfeld_generieren)
            Startknopf.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=3)

    count += 1


def deactivate_button():
    for button in buttons:
        try:
            button.config(state="disabled")
        except:
            pass


Display = tk.Tk()
Display.geometry("600x700")
Display.title("Tic Tac Toe")

Startknopf = tk.Button(Display, text="Start the game", command=spielfeld_generieren)
Startknopf.pack()


Display.mainloop()


Wow Thank you. That is another great way to do it.
